# Should I train embeddings using data from both training,validating and testing corpus?

Tags: nlp, word-embedding

I am in a case that I don't have any pre-trained words embedding for my domain (Vietnamese food reviews). so I got a though of embedding from the general and specific corpus.

And the point here is can I use the dataset of training, test and validating (did preprocess) as a source for creating my own word embeddings. If don't, hope you can give your experience.

Based on my intuition, and some experiments a wide corpus appears to be better, but I'd like to know if there's relevant research or other relevant results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I use the dataset of training, test and validating (did
>   preprocess) as a source for creating my own word embeddings

Sure, embeddings are not your features for your machine learning model. They are the "computational representation" of your data. In short, they are made of words represented in a vector space. With embeddings, your data is less sparse. Using word embeddings could be considered *part of the pre-processing step* of NLP.

Usually (I mean, using the most used technique, word2vec), the representation of a word in the vector space is defined by its surroundings (the words that it commonly goes along with).

Therefore, **to create embeddings, the larger the corpus, the better**, since it can better place a word vector in the vector space (and hence compare it to other similar words).

Comment: I do really really love your explanations. However, I am pretty confused **'the right'** of model's accuracy (with this method we can somehow down OOV problem).

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you ment by "I am pretty confused 'the right' of model's accuracy"

Comment: What I meant here is if I do train model on dataset (has used for creating words embedding), it will increase the accuracy of the model in that case ( so we can’t exactly evaluate our model if it is in a wore situation )

Comment: You'll have to keep the dataset divided. You'll only join it to make the embeddings training. So you have training and testing set for machine learning and embeddings set = training+testing set. Otherwise you may end with overfitting.